# AWS RDS - Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I have a spring boot 2 application with AWS MySQL.

MySQL has been created in AWS RDS and the inbound rule is set to "All Traffic" for testing.

Able to connect to mysql from my local machine mysqlworkbench. But, getting error if I connect from my Spring boot based application from my local.

Public Accessibility is also set to Yes. Not sure what config is missing?

**Error**

```
    2020-08-15 21:14:53.959  INFO [,,,] 22477 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2020-08-15 21:14:54.172  INFO [,,,] 22477 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-08-15 21:15:25.181 ERROR [,,,] 22477 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:324) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.DialectResolver$DefaultDialectProvider.getDialect(DialectResolver.java:106) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.DialectResolver.lambda$getDialect$0(DialectResolver.java:76) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(ArrayList.java:1601) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:543) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.DialectResolver.getDialect(DialectResolver.java:78) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.AbstractJdbcConfiguration.jdbcDialect(AbstractJdbcConfiguration.java:144) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:635) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:884) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:62) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.estimate.service.EstimateServiceApplication.main(EstimateServiceApplication.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[na:na]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readMessage(NativeProtocol.java:538) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readServerCapabilities(NativeProtocol.java:490) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.beforeHandshake(NativeProtocol.java:377) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1340) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:157) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:956) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    ... 67 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedRead(NioSocketImpl.java:283) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:309) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:982) ~[na:na]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:107) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:150) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:180) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:132) ~[na:na]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.FullReadInputStream.readFully(FullReadInputStream.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:45) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readMessage(NativeProtocol.java:532) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    ... 73 common frames omitted
```

Spring boot Connection properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://HOST_NAME:3306/DB_NAME?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=XXXXXX
spring.datasource.password=XXXXXX
```

**Versions**

```
Java version - 14
Spring boot version - 2.3.3
mysql-connector-java - 8.0.21
MySQL DB engine version in AWS RDS - 8.0.20

Local MySQL Workbench to AWS MySQL - Working
nc -vz <RDS_MYSQL_HOSTNAME> 3306 - Working

My Springboot application with local MySQL - Working

AWS RDS MySQL instance - db.t2.micro
```

Comment: have you come across this yet? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql

Comment: Does this failure happen immediately or after the application has been running for a while?

Comment: @Parsifal, It happens when the server gets started and server stops with this error.

Comment: @RisingSun, My application works with local mysql and am able to connect to remote mysql with mysql workbench, but application fails with this error while connecting to the remote server.

Comment: do you have this line `spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`?

Comment: @RisingSun, Yes, I do

Comment: try digging through your mysql logs and see if you can find the connection attempts from your application https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/failed-login-rds-mysql/

Comment: Are you running MySQL version 5.6 or above?

Comment: It appears that you have successfully connected the TCP socket, because this exception is happening in code that tries to read from an existing connection. I think that the error message about not having received any packets isn't relevant, but the message that it's been 0 milliseconds since the last packet was sent may be. That indicates that there's a too-short read timeout, but the default (0) is no timeout. So my best guess is that the driver is using a protocol that's not supported by the server.

Comment: It's also possible that there's a firewall rule somewhere that's blocking the return packets, but that should have prevented the underlying TCP connection.

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server?
Which AWS RDS model are you using? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 4 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @user1578872 Let us know when you have posted additional information, please.

Answer (score 0):

There is one possibility that might be causing this and I had a somewhat similar issue.
Related to JVM DNS Cache TTL. The problem occurs because the default is to cache a DNS forever and because AWS resources IP Address changes and so it shouldn't be set to cache forever.
Refer [java-dg-jvm-ttl](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-jvm-ttl.html)

globally, for all applications that use the JVM. Set networkaddress.cache.ttl in the **$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security** file:

```
networkaddress.cache.ttl=60
```

for your application only, set networkaddress.cache.ttl in your application’s initialization code:

```
java.security.Security.setProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl" , "60");
```